# Asking for Shortening probation period

Tags: professionalism, probation

I just joined a office, and it's been a half month, I travel for 1.5 hours to get to work, but now I am thinking of getting a house near my work as it become too difficult for me to commute as I am not allowed drive due to restrictions in my visa. Is is professional to ask the boss to cut the time for probation for the above reason? The reason I am not shifting before asking or before probation period is that I am afraid I might lose job due to any reason during probation

Comment: How long would the commute be if you could drive? Have you looked into carpooling with any colleagues that live in your area? You could offer to pay for gas rather than taking a turn driving.

Comment: You are in the honeymoon period - hold the horses and wait

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, Carpooling is a very good solution.

Comment: @Nofel, you can ask your company's admin to see if she knows anyone who lives close to you. Two weeks into a job is way to short to ask for cutting the probationary period.

Comment: Why not rent something closer to work rather than buying right away?

Comment: Unless you are in a union or have a contract that specifies otherwise for the most part you can be terminated for any reason any way.

Comment: Are you sure about that visa/driving restriction? Sounds strange. What country are you in? I have a driving license from the country in which I'm working on a visa so ...

Comment: @DavidK yes renting is the right way.

Comment: @brhans my visa has been gone for renewal purpose.

Comment: I moved to a different state in the US while by visa was being renewed and.for me, having my passport & documentation showing that my renewal was in progress (I-797A) was sufficient for a short-term (120 day) license. Once I got everything back I got a 3-year license.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probation is there for both sides,  making sure you are right for the job,  and making sure the job is right for you.

Now it's perfectly possible for an employer to decide they are happy with what they've seen and cut probation short,  and some companies don't do it at all.

But you can't really force it,  especially 2 weeks into a job.

The time is there to allow you to show your skills,  and be enough that a misstep on the way has time to be countered by positives.

You might find pushing it,  that an employer who has mixed feelings (but could turn onto your side)  may be forced into saying no

I'd bide your time and see how it goes before moving.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea, this isn't a good reason for cutting probation, it's not really a reason at all. If you don't move, and have no probation, you'll still have a 1.5 hour commute. It's really up to you to manage that, not the company.

Answer (score 3):

**Is it professional to ask the boss to cut the time for probation for the above reason?**

In general, it's not unprofessional to ask for the probationary period to be shortened for a reasonable predicament.

Unfortunately, I'm concerned about what may go through your boss' mind if you ask in this particular case. Your boss might think, "Why doesn't my employee learn how to drive and get a car?"

Don't you think it would be wise for you to learn how to drive and buy a car? A driver's license and a car are essential these days...in the USA at least. In my opinion, it looks silly/unprofessional not to have them.

I think for your case I would avoid asking the question.

Comment: Driving isn't always feasible, or practical in some places.

Comment: I know huge amount of people who do not have a car, most probably are not silly and considered as highly professional.

Comment: @Inquisitive I know how to drive but due to my passport restriction, i cannot.

Comment: *"A driver's license and a car are essential these days...in the USA at least"* this might be true for rural areas, but are you sure this holds water for metropolitan areas? I can't really say this for the USA, but here in Germany it's perfectly fine not to have a car (at least for my generation) when you are living in a mid-sized to bigger city.

Answer (score 3):

As for the people who think driving to work is the solution: The world is bigger than you think. Due to various reasons, among them cost, traffic jams, lack of parking space, or social acceptance (not everyone here is from the US), driving isn't the solution to all problems.

That said, **asking** for a shorter probation period is certainly not unprofessional, **if** the company already had time to get to know your work ethics and skills (at least a month), **and** you have a sensible reason for asking for such a favor. Just tell them you really like the work there and you consider moving closer in order to shorten the commute, and ask them if they'd be willing to shorten the probation period, contingent on you moving closer to the office. Ideally you ask that during the next performance review, if one is coming up soon.

Denying such a request also isn't unprofessional, so don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the United States -- especially in a venue with at-will employment -- the probation period has **absolutely** nothing to do with how long you're going to last on a job.  So friend, using this as a basis as to whether you should move, or not, is ultimately meaningless.  In the US, an employer **does not have to keep you for any specific duration after a probation period**.

Obviously, you want to stay *employed*.  Are you moving closer to where *a lot* of work is available, or *further away*?  You could lose that job you're on, even today or tomorrow.  The business could be bankrupt, or bought out with the intention to not replace your position.  That said, make your move with "plan b" in mind.

All that said, you could ask your boss but if it's a lot of paperwork your request might be more work than the boss is willing to do.  A half-month isn't really a lot of time to assess the value of a new employee.  You may come off as someone who's pushy, or overconfident.  If I were your boss, I'd want to know why you think I should try to override company policy on your behalf, **for reasons that benefit the business**.  If you can't give a super-great answer to such a question, then be very careful of asking for special treatment.